# responsive background image does't fill full page length at mobile size

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website with a fixed background with scrolling content here: www.grandcollapse.com

The image is perfectly fixed and you can scroll down fine, however at mobile level the image seems to only take the upper portion of the viewport. The code I am using for the background I'm using is here (css):

body {

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%), url(img/background.png) fixed;

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-position: center fixed;
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `background-size: cover` or other available values for this [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: I tried different variables using this, all fixed but repeated despite the 'no-repeat' value selected in the repeat property. Am satisfied with this anyway so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your div container blocks the background, adding a margin to it fixes it, you will need to use a media query to apply in mobile size